# Google maps compass location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

How do I change the compass location, using swift, on a google map view?

Current answers on Stack Overflow are outdated.

Previous answers here:

[How to change myLocationButton position from a GMSMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182308/how-to-change-mylocationbutton-position-from-a-gmsmapview)

[Moving the google maps compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269364/moving-the-google-maps-compass)

I tried this to no avail:

```
//move position on google compass
    for object in mapView!.subviews {
        if object.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsView" {
            for view in object.subviews {
                if view.theClassName == "GMSx_QTMButton" {
                    var frame = view.frame
                    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 110 // Move the button 110 up
                    view.frame = frame
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

extension:

```
extension NSObject {
var theClassName: String {
    return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
}
```

}