# Edit google maps compass location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

How do I change the compass location on a google map view using swift?

Answers on Stack Overflow are absurdly outdated. Please help! I asked this question a while ago but no one answered. I'm exhausted, my attempts at a solution have all failed, and my self esteem is at an all time low.

Previous answers here:

[How to change myLocationButton position from a GMSMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182308/how-to-change-mylocationbutton-position-from-a-gmsmapview)

[Moving the google maps compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269364/moving-the-google-maps-compass)

My Attempt:

```
//move position on google compass
for object in mapView!.subviews {
    if object.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsView" {
        for view in object.subviews {
            if view.theClassName == "GMSx_QTMButton" {
                var frame = view.frame
                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 110 // Move the button 110 up
                view.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***extension:***

```
extension NSObject {
    var theClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using that extension, there's already a way to get the class name returned as a string, please update to the following approach

```
  for object in mapView!.subviews {
        if String(describing: object.self) == "GMSUISettingsView" {
        ...
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for sub1 in gMapView.subviews {     
 if String(describing: type(of: sub1)) == "GMSUISettingsPaddingView" {
     for sub2 in sub1.subviews {
         if String(describing: type(of: sub2)) == "GMSUISettingsView" {
             for sub3 in sub2.subviews {
                 if String(describing: type(of: sub3)) == "GMSCompassButton"...
```